# Which of the following vector spaces are isomorphic? [on my last try]

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So far I have tried for the first problem: A&B, B&C, A&B&C
and for the second problem B&C&D, A&B&C&D, & A

However, they have turned out to be wrong. I know what isomorphic means.
[image]

Comment: Why did you try those combinations?

Comment: I know for a fact that A for the first problem and C for the second problem are the right answers by the definition of isomorphic. other than that, I tried the other combinations because i had a feeling that they were right.

Comment: When you know that A is correct, picking B&C seems odd. And how did you get C to be correct for the second one?

Comment: Let us begin with the basics: what's the dimension of Span$\{a\cos t+b\sin t\;:\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R\}\;$ ? And at least one of your facts is false: (C) isn't the correct answer to the second problem.

Comment: itn't the dimension of that 1x1? also, i thought c was correct since 2 dimensions would fit inside 3 dimensions. i don't know if that's a dumb way to think of it, but it seemed logical at the time.

Comment: You said by the definition of isomorphic. What is your definition of isomorphic?

Comment: that a is the same as b? so in this problem i think we are trying to find out which of the choices are the same as what the question is asking...

Comment: What $a$ and $b$?

Comment: so in this case a would be y=acos... and b would be one of the multiple choice possibilities.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please write the definition of isomorphic you have been given.

Comment: @Toodles I honestly think you need to go over the basics on this subject again as you seem to be missing some quite important details. What does "so in this case y=acos..." can possibly mean? How can the dimension of whatever be $\;1\times 1\;$ if dimension has to be a non negative integer? Do yourself a favour and *read* again the basics about dimension ,linear independence, generating sets and etc., and **then** approach this problem, and if then you still need help then ask.

Comment: ok i think i'm going to go over the book again. also, that was the definition of isomorphism that i was given. that two things are equal to one another.

Comment: I highly doubt that was the definition you were given. Please look it up again.

Comment: ...and if you were really given that definition then it is as wrong as one can fear something to be in mathematics. Remember that also the web is flooded with hundreds of thousands of sites, videos, papers, books, articles, etc. dealing with this. You can use them and profit greatly from them.